# What happens if you make too many calls to CompletableFuture.runAsync()?

Tags: java, concurrency, completable-future

so I'm facing a situation where I'm writing a java application to react to some events. Each event received needs to be handled and the handling could take some time. So what my application is doing the following basically:

- It receives the event.
- It calls `CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> EventProcessor.process(event));`

i.e

```
Class EventHandler implements Handler {

   public void handleEvent(Event event) {
      CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> EventProcessor.process(event));
   }

}
```

My questions are:

- What happens if I receive plenty of events? Since processing an event can take some time (e.g. 10 minutes)
- How are the backgrounds tasks managed and scheduled? would they get killed? if yes, how can I control the scheduling/termination behavior?

Comment: From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html): “All *async* methods without an explicit Executor argument are performed using the [ForkJoinPool.commonPool()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool())”  Most likely, some of the submitted tasks would not get executed until others finished, freeing up threads in the thread pool.

Answer (score 3):

*What happens if I receive plenty of events? Since processing an event can take some time (e.g. 10 minutes)*

new tasks occupy some memory, so OutOfMemoryException can occur.
Then, they are enqueued to an Executor. When enqueueing, RejectedExecutionException can be thrown if the input queue of the executor is limited in size.

*How are the backgrounds tasks managed and scheduled? would they get killed? if yes, how can I control the scheduling/termination behavior?*

if task is successfully submitted, it will be executed sooner of later. Only you can cancel it explicitly. Of course, if you submit 1000 10-minute tasks, you can wait the result for several days.

Comment: `if the input queue of the executor is limited in size`

how to control the size of the queue?

Comment: Prepare your own executor with unbounded queue.  LinkedBlockingQueue is best choice for your case. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: As said in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63886402/#comment112972105_63886402), when no executor has been specified, the common `ForkJoinPool` is used and at the end of [its class documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html), it says: “*This implementation rejects submitted tasks (that is, by throwing RejectedExecutionException) only when the pool is shut down or internal resources have been exhausted.*” (and the common pool can’t be shut down).